# Is there anyway to hide a HTML5 Video after it has finished playback and be replaced with a `Play Again` Button

Tags: html, html5-video

I have the code below for adding video to a site:

```
<video src="Alcohol Awareness.mov" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" poster="wine.png">
<p>If you are reading this, it means your browser does not support HTML5 Video or you need Quicktime</p>
</video>
```

I just needed to know if there was anyway I could get the video to be replaced by a 'Play Again' button after it finished the video, and if I could get that button to restart the Video? And Perhaps a close video button.
Similar to the way Apple has or had on it's website.

All help is appreciated.